# Is there a way to make moment.js output "1 day" instead of "a day"?

Tags: momentjs

I'm using the [Time to X](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/) function of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). When the second parameter is `true`, then the result is `a day`. Is there a way to make this `1 day` through the API, or will I need to do a string replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string.replace method to replace `"a day"` with `"1 day"`.

Or you can try like this:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
var differenceInMillisec = a.diff(b);
var differenceInDays = a.diff(b, 'days'); //Output 1 day
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But I'm guessing there are other variations that I would have to worry about. For example, `an hour` instead of `1 hour`. I guess I can just do a string replace with `a` and `an` and replace it with `1`. But am I missing anything?

Comment: @DavidJones:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah...I haven't looked at the `diff` function. That may be the way to go.

Comment: @DavidJones:- Yes that may do what you want! :)

Comment: I tried a simple string replace but it seems brittle and slightly more risky. Using `diff` gives me full control, so I'm going to mark this answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, sometimes when the result is very simple, just go for it. a string replace is just one line of code... Even if there is a solution with the api, I'm sure it would be more "complicated" than doing a string replace... or just write a reusable function and call that function on the result like : replaceString(Time_to_X); where replaceString is a function using a string replace

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and see if I can break it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple 100% solution to your question:

```
moment.localeData()._relativeTime.d = '1 day'; // override 
console.log( moment.duration(1, 'days') );     // = '1 day', not 'a day'.
```

here's a fiddle with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/ichepurnoy/6bxujv8j/

Comment: Moderators, please, do not delete this answer. It has been edited, and contains a solution to OP's question.