# Add day(s) after number with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I use moment.js and I just want to add the word "day(s)" after a number. Ex:

```
Moment(3).function('dd') // 3 days
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a more elegant solution, imho:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35705834/1691640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) with some character escaping:

```
moment(3).format('d [day(s)]'); // 3 day(s)
```

```js
alert(moment(3).format('d [day(s)]')); // 3 day(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```